# matplotlib - values between range are plotted outside of the plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following y, x values:

```
1.0 0.06
1.0 0.09
1.0 0.12
1.0 0.16
1.0 0.19
1.0 0.22
1.0 0.25
1.0 0.28
1.0 0.31
1.0 0.34
1.0 0.38
1.0 0.41
1.0 0.44
1.0 0.47
1.0 0.5
1.0 0.53
1.0 0.56
0.95 0.56
0.95 0.59
0.95 0.62
0.95 0.66
0.96 0.69
0.96 0.72
0.96 0.75
0.96 0.78
0.93 0.78
0.93 0.81
0.93 0.84
0.93 0.88
0.94 0.91
0.94 0.94
0.91 0.94
```

all I want is plot those Y, X values in a plot with ticks going from 0 to 1 with .1 step sizes.

here's what I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.grid()

ax.set_xticks([0,.1,.2,.3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1])
ax.set_yticks([0,.1,.2,.3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1])

ax.plot(r, p)

plt.show()
```

and here's what I get instead:

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNoUK.png)

Comment: I suspect your data is being read in as strings instead of floats, and thus is being plotted as categorical data by matplotlib. First thing to check: what is the data type of `r` and `p` after you have read them in? If they are strings, try converting to floats before plotting.

Answer (score 0):

That's what i get when i run your code as is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1.0, 0.06],
[1.0, 0.09],
[1.0, 0.12],
[1.0, 0.16],
[1.0, 0.19],
[1.0, 0.22],
[1.0, 0.25],
[1.0, 0.28],
[1.0, 0.31],
[1.0, 0.34],
[1.0, 0.38],
[1.0, 0.41],
[1.0, 0.44],
[1.0, 0.47],
[1.0, 0.5],
[1.0, 0.53],
[1.0, 0.56],
[0.95, 0.56],
[0.95, 0.59],
[0.95, 0.62],
[0.95, 0.66],
[0.96, 0.69],
[0.96, 0.72],
[0.96, 0.75],
[0.96, 0.78],
[0.93, 0.78],
[0.93, 0.81],
[0.93, 0.84],
[0.93, 0.88],
[0.94, 0.91],
[0.94, 0.94],
[0.91, 0.94],])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.grid()

ax.plot(arr[:, 0], arr[:, 1])

ax.set_xticks([0,.1,.2,.3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1])
ax.set_yticks([0,.1,.2,.3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1])

plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

answer:
you have a bug somewhere outside the code you're showing
perhaps the values you're plotting are not the values you're showing in the quesiton.